# Transparently inherit Django model attributes

Tags: python, django

I've been wracking my brain about how to implement the following functionality on Django 1.7. I've got two Django models. Some of the fields on one are duplicated on the other. They are related with a foreign key, like so.

```
class MyModelGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    shared_attr1 = models.NullBooleanField()
    shared_attr2 = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True, blank=True)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(MyModelGroup, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    shared_attr1 = models.NullBooleanField()
    shared_attr2 = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True, blank=True)
```

`MyModel` may be related to a `MyModelGroup` record. When `shared_attr1` or `shared_attr2` are changed on `MyModel` I want to implement the following behaviour:

1. If the foreign key is null, just save the value on `MyModel`.
2. If the foreign key is not null, and the value is different to the value shared on the record linked with the foreign key, save the value on `MyModel`.
3. Otherwise, leave the value blank.

Then, when I retrieve the value from either of the shared attributes on `MyModel`, I want it to do the following:

1. If the foreign key is null, return the value of the attribute on `MyModel`.
2. If the foreign key is not null, and the value on `MyModel` is different to the value on `MyModelGroup`, return the value on `MyModel`.
3. If the foreign key is not null, and the value on `MyModel` is null, return the value on `MyModelGroup`.

The aim is to allow a bunch of `MyModel` to inherit values from `MyModelGroup`, with the possibility of overriding those values by storing different values on `MyModel`.

I have tried implementing `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` on `MyModel` to transparently take care of checking if the foreign key exists and getting and setting the values if appropriate, but Django is doing a lot of magic stuff that is making this difficult.

I also tried implementing it with computed fields, like so:

```
@property
def shared_attr1(self):
    # renamed model field to _shared_attr1
    if self.group and self._shared_attr1 is None:
        return self.group._shared_attr1

    return self._shared_attr1

@shared_attr1.setter
def shared_attr1(self, new_value):
    if self.group is None or new_value != self.group._shared_attr1:
        self._shared_atttr1 = new_value
```

Neither of these approaches work the way I expect. Have any of you implemented something like this before?

Comment: Wouldn't that lead to serious inconsistencies. Imagine you create a model, with values `'A'` and `'B'`, then you create a `Group` (that group gets the values `'A'` and `'B'`, but then you create another `Model` for that group, and set values `'C'` and `'D`'. Then the group has two models: one with `(A, B)`, and one with `(C, D)`. It also results in data duplication, which is usually an *anti-pattern*.

Comment: An idea could perhaps be, to construct some sort of "*virtual*" group for every `Model` that has no group, and encode the values at the group level. This stores the data at one point (a group), and makes it less cumbersome to update.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Seems like a common use case to me. E.g. we have a default delivery time on the shipping partner, but can override it on each of their individual products.

Comment: @schwobaseggl: correct, but here we move "up" to the group. In that case it would be better I think to use aggregation, etc. Typically *data duplication*, makes programs a lot harder to debug, since all "transactions" need to ensure that this data duplication remains.

Comment: In case we move down in the hierarchy (a model that inherits from a group), then it would probably be a good idea to use things like derived fields, that first inspect if values are set for the object, and if not, fallback on the group.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Precisely. That is an identical use case to the one I have. Default values for the group that can be changed and are inherited by items in the group, unless the values on the item have been explicitly set.

I fail to see how this results in data duplication or is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

From my perspective the best way of having such functionality is to create [Custom Django Field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-model-fields/#preprocessing-values-before-saving). Use [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-model-fields/#preprocessing-values-before-saving) to adjust value before save.

Than define getter for the field and as the setter use [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.pre_save) method to convert value before it goes to database.

See [You can see django.db.fields](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py) for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to be too fancy. Why not have a very simple method on 'MyModel' to return the appropriate value:

```
def get_shared_attr1(self):
    if self.shared_attr1:
        return self.shared_attr1
    if self.group:
        return self.group.shared_attr1
    return None
```

And handle the maintaining of a proper state in `save`:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.group and self.shared_attr1 == self.group.shared_attr1:
        self.shared_attr1 = ''        
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

You would have to handle the case where the attribute is changed on the group in the group's `save`:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.mymodel_set.filter(shared_attr1=self.shared_attr1).update(shared_attr1='')        
    super(MyModelGroup, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I might have to do this. The problem is that I have an existing model that is being used everywhere in a fairly large codebase and if I make an accessor method to encapsulate that behaviour I'm going to have to edit hundreds of files, so I would like to maintain the standard interface, if at all possible.

Comment: There are also things like Django Rest Framework ModelViewSets that will break if I change the current interface.

Comment: Well, you could make the accessor a property having  the previous fieldname. Then you will have to change the the fieldname, of course, which breaks existing   queries.

Comment: BTW, what exactly is not working about your property getter/setter approach?

Comment: One of the attributes that I want to inherit is a foreign key to another model. When I changed the names of the fields and implemented getters and setters for that, my Django Rest Framework model views complain that the object is not serializable.